# Determining the week of the year

Tags: php, date

I have a script that im working on that has a the need for me to determine what week of the year i am in. and this has to go year by year.

So the script must determine the week of the year i am on now. ie week 33
then it must also work out that last week was week 32 and next week 34

I will then be able to match them up with the database and pull out only content for this week.

i have simple named the weeks a number in the database... ie... 34 33 and 35

Please see attached image

Any help appreciated !
Ta

[image]

Comment: My appologies to all... I am looking at the answers but will only tackle this date issue when i get the to part in my project!. thank you all for your input !.

Answer (score 3):

You only want the week number?

```
date('W')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it in MySQL then (I think this can force the MySQL not to cache the query so there can be a performance issue)

```
SELECT WEEK(now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's [DateTime class](http://php.net/datetime):-

```
$week = (int)(new \DateTime())->format('W');
$previousWeek = $week - 1;
$followingWeek = $week + 1;
```